# What is the correct SQL command to replace Char(150) with a UTF-8 compatible dash in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, sql-server-2016

I have a SQL Server 2016 database TableName with an nvarchar(255) column. Some entries contain Char(150), which renders as the dreaded black diamond when I push it out as HTML. I want to convert those black diamonds into a simple dash.

I would like to do this with a simple SQL Update + Replace command using the Char() function.

None of these are working, and I don't understand why:

```sql
Update TableName Set FieldName = REPLACE(FieldName, 'CHAR(150)', '-')

Update TableName Set FieldName = REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), FieldName), 'CHAR(150)', '-')
```

It does, however, work if I use '–', '-' instead of 'CHAR(150)', '-' but I am interested in getting the CHAR(150) version to work, as I have several other black-diamond issues to fix.

I'm aware that I should have avoided this problem from the start by not allowing smart quotes, etc. into my database. No need to remind me of that. I'm also aware that SQL Server 2016 doesn't support UTF-8 per se. At this point, I'm just wondering why a simply Update+Replace is not working, whereas tons of articles seem to recommend this syntax that is not working for me.

Additional info that may be helpful:

1. I'm certain that CHAR(150) is in the database because I can do a select that gets back the results I expect:

```sql
.... where FieldName like '%[CHAR(150)]%'
```

2. I'm certain that my data is not getting updated by the commands above that use Char(150) because I visually inspect the table after running the command. To ensure it's not just a question of my eye not seeing the change, I even have tried replace CHAR(150) with a word like 'DOG' -- no luck. It is definitely not working.

Thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

p.s. I know this is seemingly one of those "already covered extensively elsewhere" questions, but I've read many articles/pages and none of them seems to directly address this command's not working. I couldn't find the answer, or anyone else running into this exact problem.

Comment: You have the CHAR(150) in quotes on your top query.  It will search for that as a string of CHAR(150), not the actual character.  Try removing the single quotes.

Comment: `'CHAR(150)'` doesn't look for the character `–`, it would look for the **literal string** `'CHAR(150)'`. Don't encapsulate functions in single quotes.

Comment: Oh, man. I feel stupid for having missed that. I'm trying it without quotes now.

Comment: Wow, that was all it was. Thanks so much to both of you.